# Getting abnormal result from angular model class function

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, sequelize.js

I have a simple Invoicing & Inventory management application where we display the list of invoices under a particular customer which you can see in the img below. Also, when we click on **`View/Edit`** button the bootstrap modal pop-up is displayed with the selected invoice details. The problem I notice here is, the result of **`Grand Total`** function is wrong which I being a novice in angular unable to figure out.

I also read about the **impact of function calls in angular template** here https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496 because I'm calling the functions in my template code below. I tired the pipe soultion shown in the article but that didn't help me.

Looking for someone who can help me figure out the `Grand Total` issue. Any help is really appreciated. **Kindly look at the images & code below for the reference.**

**1. Invoice lists under customer(Raj Kapoor)**

[image: invoices-under-customer]

**2. Invoice Bootstrap Modal Pop-up (On click of View/Edit Button)**

**`Note:`** Here, assume that we've edited invoice no 4

[image: invoice-pop-up]

**3. Template code(admin-invoices.component.html)**

**`Note:`** I'm providing only the absolute essentials part of code to keep it simple to understand. **Focus only on 2 things:** 1. View/Edit button function call  2. Invoice amount calculations section

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row g-0 mb-4">
      <!-- Customer Name & Total Balance code goes here -->
    </div>
    
    <table class="table table-hover border" datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <!-- Table heading goes here like Date, Invoice No., 
                Amount, Balance Due, Operation, Action etc. 
                -->
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let invoice of customerInvoices">
                    <td class="text-center">{{invoice.invoiceDate | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
                    <td class="text-center">{{invoice.invoiceNumber}} </td>
                    <td class="text-center">{{invoice.invoiceTotal | currency:'INR':true}}</td>
                    <td class="text-center">{{invoice.invoiceTotal - invoice.paymentTotal | currency:'INR':true}}</td>
                    <td class="text-center">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="setInvoice(invoice)" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#invoiceDetailsModal">
                            View/Edit Details
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <!-- View/Edit Details: Bootstrap Modal Starts -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="invoiceDetailsModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="invoiceDetailsLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <!-- Shop Details header goes here. -->                       
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body pt-0">
                    <div class="row">
                       <!-- To Customer, Date and Invoice No goes here-->
                    </div>
        
                    <!-- Items List Section -->
                    <div class="row">    
                        <div class="items-table">  
                            <div class="row header">
                              <!-- Table Heading: Sr. No, Item Details, 
                              Qty, Rate, Amt goes here.. -->
                            </div>
        
                            <ng-container *ngFor="let invItem of invoice.invoiceItem; let i=index;">
                              <!-- Table data(list of all items) goes here-->    
                            </ng-container>
        
                            <!-- Invoice amount calculations section -->
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-4">
                                    <!-- sub total row -->
                                    <div class="row" style="border: 1px solid green;">
                                        <div class="col-6 text-end">Sub Total:</div>
                                        <div class="col text-center">{{invoiceSubTotal() | currency:'INR':true}}</div>
                                    </div>
        
                                    <!-- discount row -->
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-6 ps-0 pe-0 text-end">
                                            Discount: 
                                           <select class="form-select p-0" style="display: inline; width:60px;" [(ngModel)]="invoice.discountLabel" name="discountLabel" id="discountLabel" aria-label="Select discount option">
                                                <option value="%">%</option>
                                                <option value="Rs">Rs</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>                        
                                        <div class="col text-center">
                                            <input [(ngModel)]="invoice.discountTotal" name="discountTotal" type="number" style="border: 1px solid #ddd; width:100px">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
        
                                    <!-- freight row -->
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-6 text-end">Freight(Rs.):</div>
                                        <div class="col text-center"><input [(ngModel)]="invoice.freight" name="freight" type="number" style="border: 1px solid #ddd; width:100px"></div>
                                    </div>
        
                                    <!-- grand total row -->
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-6 text-end">Grand Total:</div>
                                        <div class="col text-center">{{calculateGrandTotal() | currency: 'INR':true}}</div>
                                    </div>
        
                                    <!-- Received row -->
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-6 text-end">Received:</div>
                                        <div class="col text-center">
                                            <input [(ngModel)]="invoice.paymentTotal" name="paymentTotal" type="number" style="border: 1px solid #ddd; width:100px">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>    
                    </div> 
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-bs-dismiss="modal" (click)="clearData()">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" (click)="updateInvoice()">
                        Update & Print
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- View/Edit Details: Bootstrap Modal Ends -->
```

**4. Component Class(admin-invoices.component.ts)**

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-invoices',
  templateUrl: './admin-invoices.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-invoices.component.css']
})
export class AdminInvoicesComponent {
  customerInvoices: Invoice[] = []; // to get list of all invoices under this customer
  invoice: Invoice = new Invoice(); 
  
  customerId: number; 
  customer: Customer = new Customer(); // To avoid initial undefined value of customer field
  totalBalance: number = 0.0; // total balace of all invoices under this customer
  
  itemsList: Item[] = []; 

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, 
              private customerService: CustomerService, 
              private invoiceService: InvoiceService, 
              private itemService: ItemService) {
    this.customerId = +(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('customerId')); // converting string to number using '+'
    
    this.setCustomer();
    this.setItems(); 

  this.invoiceService.getCustomerInvoices(this.customerId)
      .subscribe((invoices: Invoice[]) => {
        this.customerInvoices = invoices.map(invoice => new Invoice(invoice)); 
        
        this.calculateTotalBalance(); // get the total balace of all invoices under this customer
      });
  }

  setCustomer() {
    this.customerService.get(this.customerId)
    .subscribe((customer: Customer) => this.customer = customer);
  }

  setItems() {
     this.itemService.getAll()
     .subscribe((items: Item[]) => this.itemsList = items);
  }
  
  calculateTotalBalance() {
    this.customerInvoices.forEach(invoice => {
      this.totalBalance = this.totalBalance + (invoice.invoiceTotal - invoice.paymentTotal);
    });
  }

  setInvoice(invoice: Invoice) {
    this.invoice = invoice;
  }

  addItem() {
    this.invoice.addItem();
  }

  removeItem(item) {
    this.invoice.removeItem(item);
  }

  invoiceSubTotal() {
    return this.invoice.invoiceSubTotal();
  }

  calculateGrandTotal() {
    return this.invoice._invoiceTotal;
  } 

  updateInvoice() {
    // update code goes here
  }

}
```

**5. Invoice Model class(invoice.ts)**

```js
export class Invoice {
    invoiceId?: number;
    invoiceNumber: number;
    discountLabel: string = '';
    discountTotal: number = 0.0;
    freight: number = 0.0;
    invoiceTotal: number = 0.0;
    paymentTotal: number = 0.0;
    invoiceDate: string;
    narration: string = '';
    
    customer: Customer;
    invoiceItem: InvoiceItem[] = [];
    description: string; 

   
    constructor(customer?: Customer, invoiceNumber?: number);
    constructor(invoice: Invoice);
    constructor(customerOrInvoice?: Customer | Invoice, invoiceNumber?: number){
        if(!invoiceNumber) {
            // Existing invoices
            Object.assign(this, customerOrInvoice); // copy everything in current invoice object
        } else {
            // New invoice creation
            this.invoiceDate = new Date().toISOString().substring(0,10);
            this.customer = customerOrInvoice as Customer; 
            this.invoiceNumber = invoiceNumber;
            this.invoiceItem.push({itemId: 0, quantity: 0, rate: 0}); // default invoice_item    
        }
    }

    addItem() {
        this.invoiceItem.push({itemId: 0, quantity: 0, rate: 0}); // default invoice_item
    }

    
    invoiceSubTotal(): number {
        let subTotal = 0.00;
    
        this.invoiceItem.forEach(item => {
            subTotal += (item.quantity * item.rate);
        });
    
        return subTotal;
    }

    get totalDiscount(): number {
        if(this.discountLabel === '%') return ((this.discountTotal * this.invoiceSubTotal())/100); 
        
        return this.discountTotal; // Considering discountLable to either 'Rs' or not selected
    }

    get _invoiceTotal(): number {
        this.invoiceTotal = (this.invoiceSubTotal() - this.totalDiscount) + this.freight; 
        
        return this.invoiceTotal;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Sure, thanks for your time & efforts in this. Sent you an email, kindly check.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would like to thank `@GRD` or `grdtechlab@gmail.com` for collaborating with me over an email to help me with this problem. This was basically two way efforts to find out the root cause. But again credit goes to `GRD`.

**`Root Cause:`** So, the backend response object was the main issue and not the UI code. Because, when we query sequelize database to get the `Decimal` type data, then it converts the **decimal values** to **string values**. And, in the resultant object, we end up with the `string` type values instead of 'number' type(in javascript). **This leads to abnormal results in our computation functions like _invoiceTotal( )  getter function above.**

Read more here https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/8019

**`Solution:`** As mentioned in the above github issue, I changed the sequelize configuration to **`dialectOptions : {decimalNumbers: true}`** and this converted all the decimal values to `number` in the response object.

See the response object images below to understand this better.

**1. Incorrect Response object (string values instead of number type)**

[image: incorrect-response-object]

**2. Correct Response object (after changing sequelize configuration)**

[image: correct-response-object]